# Count excel rows from specific index to last row - Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
for (int i = 0; i < loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
    if (loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets() <= i) return;

    loc1.sheet = loc1.workbook.getSheetAt(i);
    loc2.sheet = loc2.workbook.getSheetAt(i);

    int num1 = loc1.sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int num2 = loc2.sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
}
```

How do I count the no. of rows starting from a specific index? The above code counts the total no. of rows. loc1 and loc2 are ref variable of the class containing workbook, sheet, row, and cell variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well thats maybe a little bit stupid (and maybe I didnt get the difference between physical rows and logical), but

```
getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - specific_index;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Iterator to read the row.

```
int indexStart = 1;
Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while ( rows.hasNext() ) {
   Row row = rows.next();

   if( row.getRowNum() < indexStart  ) {
      continue;
   }

// your code
}
```